# Linq2Db wrong JOIN

Tags: inner-join, linq2db

I'm using Linq2Db from a long time and I've never have to face a mistake in the queries.

I've a function returning an `IQueryable` and then another method where I compose another query using the first one as a base.

```cs
await using var db = new Database.Database();
var pcScanHdd = GetPcScanId(db, ScanFlags.HardDisks);
//var a = await pcScanHdd.ToListAsync(); // <- Just a check: it works as expected
var query =
    from ps in pcScanHdd
    join pc in db.Pcs on ps.PcId equals pc.Id
    //ERROR: linq2db creates a wrong INNER JOIN in the next line
    join scan in db.Scan on ps.ScanId equals scan.Id
    join disk in db.LogicalHdds on scan.Id equals disk.ParentId
    where disk.MediaType == MediaTypeEnum.FixedHardDisk
            && disk.DriveType == DriveTypeEnum.LocalDisk
    select new { pc, scan, disk };
```

In this query take a look at
`join scan in db.Scan on ps.ScanId equals scan.Id`
that, unfortunately, return this query

```cs
INNER JOIN `pcs` `pc_1` ON `ps`.`PcId` = `pc_1`.`id`
INNER JOIN `scan` `scan_2` ON `ps`.`PcId` = `scan_2`.`id`
INNER JOIN `info_logicaldisk` `disk` ON `scan_2`.`id` = `disk`.`id_parent`
```

I couldn't understand why my query was returning no items, then I realized the reason watching at SQL.
It should be `INNER JOIN scan scan_2 ON ps.ScanId = scan_2.id`.

I've tried using `.Where()` in linq2sql, but it's processed exactly as the other.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
If yes, what?
If no, is there a solution?

**EDIT**
Object returned from the first query has not Linq2Db attributes because it's not persisted in db, so I fill in with a Linq2Sql query:

```cs
private record PcScanId
{
    public int PcId;
    public int ScanId;
}
```

It works as expected and if I try to check the result using

```cs
var a = await pcScanHdd.ToListAsync();
```

I get correct fields and values.
If I don't use this sub-query but only db objects instead, everything works fine.

Comment: I suspect your Linq2Db entity/table config is misconfigured - did you use Linq2Db's built-in scaffolding tooling., or did you write it by hand? Either way, please share it.

Comment: @Dai I edited my question, hope it 's clearer now

Comment: Please create issue in `linq2db` repository. It is hard to say what happened.